# Merging two ArrayLists to one ArrayList parallelly?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, parallel-processing

I need to merge two ArrayLists into one ArrayList but I need it to be done really fast, because the function that's doing this is called bunch of times. Here is my version of function :

```
  public ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> mergeIdWithGrade(ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<Integer> grades) {

    ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< id.size(); i++)
    {
        list.add(new Pair<String,Integer>(id.get(i), grades.get(i)));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Two ArrayLists that are parameters of the function, they are the same size and element at index `i` of `ArrayList<String> id` corresponds to element at index `i` of the `ArrayList<Integer> grades` (they are making pair).
The complexity of the function is obviously O(n), but I am wondering can this be done using parallelStreams, or generally in parallel using all cores of my CPU?

Comment: How many elements are in the lists? In this case, unless there's millions of elements, multi-threading is likely to make your code _slower_.

Comment: there are cca 1000 elements in the lists but the function is called 1000 times too.

Comment: Starting threads add overhead, as does the necessary synchronization between them. You can try the parallel `IntStream` approach suggested by Stepan's answer, but I'm not sure 1000 elements is enough to see any benefits considering the single mapping operation you have is trivial. However, you can benchmark the code (using JMH) to see if it multiple threads improve performance.

Comment: What does "merge" mean? Do you mean "merge" in the traditional sense, where the two given lists are _sorted_ in some order, and the final "merged" list must also be sorted in the same order? I don't know that there is any effective way to parallelize that because the algorithm must compare the "next" entry in each of the given lists at every step. On the other hand, if all you want to do is _concatenate_ the two lists, then you potentially could have two threads, each copying members from one of the two given arrays to their proper places in the final array.

Comment: One of the most important things to learn about programming is that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with other comments that parallel execution would not probably help.
Nevertheless, try this piece of code out and see whether parallel is beneficial for you or not

```
    public List<Pair<String, Integer>> mergeIdWithGrade(List<String> id, List<Integer> grades) {
      return IntStream
            .range(0, Math.min(id.size(), grades.size()))
            .parallel() // try with and without it
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pair(id.get(i), grades.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Note, here is only mapping is done in different threads. The result will be gathered by the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this function and it's not better than the old one. I tested the entire program that I have with it and it's about 0.9 secondss slower than it was :( I think in my case, there isn't a way to improve this afterall.

Comment: @therealsowho One optimization _might_ be to create the `ArrayList` with a non-default initial capacity (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(id.size())`). This helps prevent unnecessary resizing operations in the `ArrayList` (which involves allocating a new array and copying the elements over). Though, again, 1000 elements may not be enough to see a significant difference. And as noted, avoid premature optimization. Benchmark and profile code to see where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

Multithread here is a bad idea, because you cannot be sure of the state of the original list. 
Make sure it is thread safe.